# how to pass the post value to session to be use later?

Tags: php

i want to pass variable session value from post to 2nd page and so son but it doesnt work.

login page

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( isset($_POST['uname'] ) ) { $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['uname']; }
?>

<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="uname">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

now i try to open my 2nd page call index.php to check if already assigment post value to session variable but nothing value pass.

```
<?php
session_start();
    if ( isset($_SESSION['username'] ) ) { echo $_SESSION['username'];}
    ?>
```

Comment: Is that your entire second page? If so you have to call `session_start();` before the session variables are accessible. It has to be called once per http request, and there can't be any output before you call it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `session_start` first in the second page to access the session variable.

Comment: sory, i forget to add session_start(); but it doesn't work too

Comment: Is what you posted the entire page? Specifically from the begining